# MomentJS - isValid() method is not validating correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, momentjs

I'm reading the document for MomentJS for validating a moment date created from a String.

The example they gave is:

```
1) moment("not a real date").isValid(); // false
```

but if I add 1 to the end of the String and validate it, I get:

```
2) moment("not a real date 1").isValid(); // true
```

Why is it that #2 is a valid moment date object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that that constructor is now [deprecated](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).  But to answer the question:

This constructor turns around and passes the `"not a real date 1"` string into the `Date` constructor.  Take a look at this:

In Chrome:

```
new Date("not a real date 1") --> Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
new Date("not a real date")   --> Invalid Date
```

In IE11:

```
new Date("not a real date 1") --> [date] NaN[date] NaN
new Date("not a real date")   --> [date] NaN[date] NaN
```

In FireFox 42:

```
new Date("not a real date 1") --> Invalid Date
new Date("not a real date")   --> Invalid Date
```

So the answer is, it *is* validating correctly, and its a valid date object because the `Date` constructor successfully created a `Date` object.  There's a bug in the `Date` constructor, at least in some browsers.

**Edit:**

Here's the relevant part of the [ECMAScript 6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-value), emphasis mine:

> If Type(v) is String, then
>   Let tv be the result of parsing v as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse method (20.3.3.2). If the parse resulted in an abrupt completion, tv is the Completion Record.

And then, section [20.3.3.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.parse):

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules (including extended years) called out in Date Time String Format (20.3.1.16).  **If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.** Unrecognizable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN.

So, since the spec explicitly allows the browser to creatively parse the string, I guess it's not a bug.  Chrome just doesn't behave the same as the others.